# Is it possible to send HTTP POST request to Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql, graphql server?

Tags: html, laravel, graphql, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql`. Is it possible to send your queries and mutations through `HTTP POST` request instead of `HTTP GET`?
I am trying to send HTML content to Graphql server.

Comment: [You shall pass](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql/blob/develop/src/Folklore/GraphQL/routes.php#L50) On line 13 the routes are read from config, so you can configure them via config.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Thomas Moors  I could do it.

You just have to send your query or mutation through HTTP Request as json with key "query" like this:

```
{
  'query': '
    mutation createPage{
      createPage(title:"title", content:"an html content") {
        id
        content
      }
    }
'
}
```

Or based on what's been stated [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql-clients/):

```
    curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"query": "{ 
            mutation createPage{
            createPage(title:"title", content:"an html content") {
              id
              content
            }
          }

    }"}' \
    http://localhost:4000/graphql
```